# Using htaccess for wordpress attachment URLs

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess

We appear to have an issue with a bunch of old-style wordpress URLs, for example:

`http://example.com/?attachment_id=11894`

Which don't exist.

I'd like them to drop out of the index entirely, so I'd like to serve a `410 GONE` status, ideally with **.htaccess** is there a `RewriteRule` or similar pattern I can use to get rid of them for once and all?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)attachment_id= [NC]
RewriteRule / - [G]
```